# Better way to call conditionally promises

Tags: javascript, algorithm, asynchronous

I have a scenario where I have "Promise A" and "Promise B". I need to call both promises only if the variable "value" is false, else, I only need to call the Promise B.

So, I wrote this code:

```
if(!value){
            PromiseA.then((newValue)=>{
                PromiseB.then((newValue)=>{
                    //...
                })
            })
        }
        else{
            PromiseB.then((value)=>{
                //....
            })
        }
```

This code works fine, but I'm wondering if there is a better way to accomplish this than using "if-else".

This for have clean code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Promise.all()` is your friend here.

Comment: What do you mean by "call both"? In parallel? Sequentially? Your code implies it's sequentially, however, the presence of promise objects, also means that both the async tasks are already running in either case. So you're only either waiting for one to finish or for both to finish. This doesn't seem quite right.

Comment: @VLAZ sequentially. I need to wait the value returned by promise A, to execute the promise B in the first case.

Comment: So, is the async task for PromiseA already running? I'm not sure that would be "sequential" if you have two running async tasks. If you need to wait for one or both, you'd just do `await Promise.all(myPromises)` and you'd put either one or both promises in the `myPromises` array. Seems illogical to have to running tasks and "wait for them sequentially". Because B can finish before A anyway.

Comment: Do the `// ...`s contain the same code? (If not, then there's not much improvement)

Comment: @CertainPerformance yeah, contains the same code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside an async function, `await` the first Promise if you need to.

```
const firstValue = value ?? await PromiseA;
const resultOfPromiseB = await PromiseB;
// do stuff with resultOfPromiseB
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the second promise in a function if you want to avoid code repetition.

```
function callPromiseB() {
   PromiseB.then((value)=>{
      //....
   })
}

        if(!value){
            PromiseA.then((newValue)=>{
                callPromiseB()
            })
        }
        else{
            callPromiseB()
        }
```